# size of bad data on HD windows7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, filesystem-corruption

While using my external harddrive (NTFS) i had a crc32 error. Now i would like to see how much data is corrupted. If its a few KBs i wont mind but if its a few MB i should consider getting a new harddrive. How can i check using windows7

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
chkdsk volume /R
```

This will attempt to locate bad sectors on the disk and fix them if possible. Otherwise, they will be marked as bad and not used in future.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need a new hard drive. Copy all the files that are not messed up to a different disk and reformat, or just stay on the current disk and do a few `fdisk`s on it. A single write fault is certainly not good grounds for new hardware, heck, it might not have been a write fault at all but simply a random bit flip caused by a stray proton! Don't get a new drive over that, it's just a waste of money.

Comment: backup and copying a large zip to it both failed and before that i had a crc32 error on two reads and i restarted the system at least twice between these. But to the point, what fdisk commands might i use? Also if this drive goes down i will lose a lot of valueable data. Its pretty new so i thought i would be safe apart from physical damage for a few years.

Comment: @acidzombie24, you might want to consider making some backups of your data regardless.  Better safe than sorry when it comes to backing up.

Comment: Oh yes, you should certainly backup any valuable data regardless of what it's stored on. And to answer your question, I meant "chkdsk"...fdisk is the Linux disk partitioning utility, I was trying to refer to the Windows disk checking utility. I don't exactly remember the commands, running `chkdsk /help` from a command line should help you out. The basic idea is that you want to check whatever drive letter is assigned to your external HDD, running that command should tell you how.